# hawt.io create a user with specific permissions

Tags: java, hawtio

I've installed Hawt.IO and it's great for what it does, now I just want to know if it's possible to create a new user that isn't an admin, and has specific permissions.

For example a user that would only have access to some tabs, or a user that can only view graphs but can't do any editing on the settings etc.

Is this possible on hawt.io?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Work on this is underway -> https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/465

At the moment the JMX view visualizes user permissions if the JMX guard mbean from Karaf 3.x is available.  So if you install Karaf 3.x and run hawtio on it, the JMX tab will show red/green icons on mbeans and disable operations the user doesn't have privileges to invoke.

It will rely on backend support to map the current user's permissions to mbeans, so at boot hawtio will look for specific mbeans it can invoke on to find out those permissions.  With the JMX guard in place the user won't be able to execute a JMX operation he doesn't have access too.  So right now with that in place all of the views (other than JMX attributes/operations) will still show all their controls, however the backend will deny access to invoking operations the user can't invoke.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm afraid I didn't get you there, by the way I installed in on ServiceMix, are there any easy steps to achieve that role management? Is there a possibility to say "such role has access to such things in read/write/execute" ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see a response here until now!

Comment: The role based access control in hawtio kinda requires server-side support, in that you have to supply an mbean that hawtio can use to query what the current user can invoke on.  We ship a dummy mbean that hawtio falls back onto that just returns true for all mbeans/operations.  When you install hawtio into a runtime with either Karaf 3.x or 2.4 (not sure if this is out yet) then hawtio will use the mbean that Karaf exposes.  More info here -> http://coderthoughts.blogspot.com/2013/10/jmx-role-based-access-control-for-karaf.html